# what is the meaning of spatial function of Ex?

Tags: electromagnetism

I came across this while i was studying Resonant cavities. 
Consider the component of $E_x $ of $ E $.
Within the cavity $$ E_x = E_x(x,y,z) $$ Why should we take $E_x $ in all three directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to separate the component of the field we're talking about from the spatial dependence. Ok, so you have the whole electric field, which is some vector quantity:
$$
\vec{E} = E_x \hat{x} + E_y \hat{y} + E_z \hat{z}
$$
But of course the electric field can be a function of position $\vec{E}(x,y,z)$, which means that so are all of its components. We say "how large is the part of the electric field that points in the $\hat{x}$-direction, which we call $E_x$"? And we discover that the answer depends on where you are, that is, it depends on the considered coordinates $x, y, z$. Maybe I have an electric field in the $\hat{x}$ direction, but that electric field dies off with increasing position in the $z$ axis. To draw this in a field picture, I'd draw lots of horizontal arrows close to the origin, and then fewer up top. It'd be $E_x$ the whole time, but it depends on $z$.